# Server is not properly installed Message

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using Wcf service to get data from Server Side in windows application , means communication between web WCF service and window application which develop it in vb.net and WCF is also developed in vb.net.

First i create a wcf with return "hello" and i am get from the string in the Windows application.In windows application I am add wcf services in service reference.

I just publish the wcf in IIS in my local PC . Then i try it by call the service from windows application  . It was return that string "Hello".

**But My issue is ,**

when I  publish the wcf in IIS in different server which IIS access through public address. Then i access the service from my local PC , that time it return the string **"Server is not properly installed"**.

Please Provide idea to me to find out issue where it occured and how to solve it ?

Comment: Can you access and consume the service locally in server?
In your server, are the correct framework version and wcf activation installed?

Comment: Yes I solved that above question . It is problem with the framework so i change it and now it is working ..